# Python でテキストファイル内の縦並びの数字を小さい順に並び変えて、結果をコマンドプロンプトに出力したい。

Tags: python

Python初心者です。
テキストファイルを読み込むプログラムの中に2つのファンクションを入れて、最終的にバラバラの順に縦並びに配置されたテキストファイル内の数字を上から小さい順に並び変えて結果をコマンドラインに出力する練習をしています。
ですが、何度試してもエラーメッセージばかりがコマンドで出てしまい、プログラムが上手く機能しません。
下記にコードとテキストファイルの内容、本来の出力結果を記載するので、コードで間違っている部分があれば、教えて下さい。

## プログラム全体（2つのファンクションを含む）

```py
from sys import argv

def divide(p,r):
    x = A[r]
    i = p - 1

    for j in len(p, r - 1):
        if (A[j] <= x):
            i += 1
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]

    A[i+1], A[r] = A[r], A[i+1] 
    return(i+1)



def sort205(p,r):
    if (p < r):
        q = divide(p,r)
        sort205(p,q - 1)
        sort205(q + 1,r)




A = []
p = 0




if len (argv) == 1:
    print ("Type argument/filename.") 
else:
    filename = argv[1]
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            contents = file.read()
    except IOError:
        print("No File Found")
    else:
        file = open(filename)



        for line in file: 
            line = line.rstrip()
        　　A.append(line)
        r = len(A)
        sort205(p,r)
        
        print (A)
```

## テキストファイル内容

```
255
49152
128
64
4
20
500
```

## 趣旨とするコマンドライン上の出力結果

```
4
20
64
128
255
500
49152
```

## エラーメッセージ内容

```
  File "RecursionLab.py", line 52, in <module>
    sort205(p,r)
  File "RecursionLab.py", line 22, in sort205
    q = divide(p,r)
  File "RecursionLab.py", line 6, in divide
    x = A[r]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: 具体的にどんなエラーメッセージが表示されたのかも質問文に追記してみてください。

Comment: エラーメッセージ追加しました。メッセージ内容は、私なりに一部コードのミスに気付いてコードを一部編集したうえで更に出たエラーメッセージとなっています。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。ついでに、もしコードが分割されたもので無ければ質問文でもひとまとめに (=元のコードのまま) 貼り付けてみてください。どこがファンクションなのかは読めば分かりますが、エラーに出ている行番号は実際のコードと照らし合わせて確認する必要があります。

Comment: プログラム内容を全てつないで編集しなおしました。エラーメッセージは依然同じです。

Comment: エラーが発生している `x = A[r]` の部分ですが、処理を辿ってみると、`r = len(A)` になっています。そのため、`index out of range` が発生しています。また、`divide()` 関数内で、`for j in len(p, r - 1):` としている部分がありますが、ここは `len` ではなく `range` ではないでしょうか。

Comment: ```r = len(A)```　が ```index out of range```　になってしまう原因について詳しくお伺いしてもよろしいでしょうか？それと、教えて下さった内容等を新たに反映したコードとそれに伴うエラーメッセージは毎回更新すべきでしょうか？

Comment: リストのインデックス値の範囲は `0` から `len(A)-1` までになっています。なので、最初の `sort205()` 関数の呼び出し部分は `sort205(p, r-1)` になるはずです。また、`len` は `range` へ修正しておく方が良いかと思います。

Comment: それから、質問欄に記載のコードには他にも不具合があります。それらについてはおそらく Miki さん自身で解決可能なのではないかと思います。

Comment: 教えて下さった部分とそれ以外の不具合も見つけてなおすことができました。ありがとうございます。無事に動作したコードを回答欄に載せます。

Answer (score 0):

コメントで教えて下さった内容を踏まえて無事動作するようになったプログラムを下記に載せます。

```py
from sys import argv


def divide(p,r):
    x = A[r]
    i = p - 1

    for j in range(p, r):
        if (A[j] <= x):
            i += 1
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]


    A[i+1], A[r] = A[r], A[i+1]

    return(i+1)



def sort205(p,r):
    if (p < r):
        q = divide(p,r)
        sort205(p,q-1)
        sort205(q+1,r)


p = 0


if len (argv) == 1:
    print ("Type argument/filename.") 
else:
    filename = argv[1]
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            contents = file.read()
    except IOError:
        print("No File Found")
    else:
        file = open(filename,"r")
        A = file.readlines()

        for line in range(0,len(A)): 
            A[line] = int (A[line])
        r = len(A)
        sort205(0,r-1)

        print (A)
```

Comment: 分かる範囲で構わないので、(コメントの内容も踏まえて)どこを直したのか簡単な解説があるとより良い回答になると思います。